# TS2339: Property 'closest' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. - How do I get native event.target in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to construct an event listener callback that detects where it has been invoked from, similar to this:

```
import { TouchEvent } from 'react'

const isInvokedFromInsideContainer = (event: TouchEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  parentContainer = event.target.closest('#container')
  console.log('isInvokedFromInsideContainer: ' + !!parentContainer)
}
```

but I get

> TS2339: Property 'closest' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

`event.nativeEvent.target.closest` doesn't work either
`event.currentTarget.closest` works, but I obviously don't want that

Casting target as HTMLElement works:

```
const target = (event.target as HTMLElement)
const parentContainer = target.closest('#container')
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, ended up casting the type as mentioned above. Let me know if you figure it out :)

Comment: I just ended up type casting, too.

Answer (score 14):

I fixed this error by directly casting `event.target` as `HTMLElement`

So in your case:

```
...
  parentContainer = (event.target as HTMLElement).closest('#container')
...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can make Typescript understand which type the target is by asserting its constructor:

```
if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
  const container = event.target.closest('#container')
}
```

Comment: This is the solution we eventually resorted to but how would you test the "else" branch of this? Is it possible trigger a click of a non HTMLElement?